# html link buttons centered on page

Tags: html, css, button

Currently I am trying to create some links that look like buttons. It's working fairly well, except I want to be able to align them horizontally. This what I have so far:

```css
.border {
  display: table;
  width: 220px;
  height: 120px;
  border: 2px solid #1E5034;
  transition: all 250ms ease-out;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-spacing: 10px;
  float:left;
}

.border:hover {
  border-spacing: 2px;
}

a.btn {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  font: 17.5px sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #1E5034;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

a.btn:hover,
a.btn:focus,
a.btn:active,
a.btn:visited,
a.btn:link {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #1E5034;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-grp">
  <div class="border">
    <a class="btn" href="#">Some really long text link #1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="border">
    <a class="btn" href="#">Some other really long text link #2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="border">
    <a class="btn" href="#">Some more really really long text link #3</a>
  </div>
  <div class="border">
    <a class="btn" href="#">The last really long text link #4</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit**:
[image: What I am trying to achieve]

If it has `display:inline-block;` it will mess up with formatting with heights and not center the text.

I'm trying to create something as shown here, but then be able to center this on the page as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using width in `px` thats why then don't come in a single row...So try to use `%` width i.e. `25%`...

```css
.border {
  display: table;
  width: 25%;
  height: 120px;
  border: 2px solid #1E5034;
  transition: all 250ms ease-out;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-spacing: 10px;
  float: left;
}

.border:hover {
  border-spacing: 2px;
}

a.btn {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  font: 17.5px sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #1E5034;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

a.btn:hover,
a.btn:focus,
a.btn:active,
a.btn:visited,
a.btn:link {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #1E5034;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-grp">
  <div class="border">
    <a class="btn" href="#">Some really long text link #1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="border">
    <a class="btn" href="#">Some other really long text link #2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="border">
    <a class="btn" href="#">Some more really really long text link #3</a>
  </div>
  <div class="border">
    <a class="btn" href="#">The last really long text link #4</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Well I recommend you to use **Flexbox** here...It will give you the full control to align the item vertically and horizontally...Also you will need to use `:after` for the background, as `flexbox` does not allow `border-spacing`

```css
.btn-grp {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.border {
  width: 20%;
  height: 120px;
  border: 2px solid #1E5034;
  transition: all 250ms ease-out;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}

a.btn {
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  font: 16px sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  flex: 1;
}

a.btn:hover,
a.btn:focus,
a.btn:active,
a.btn:visited {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #1E5034;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.border:before {
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #1f5034;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  transform: scale(0.85);
}

.border:hover:before {
  transform: scale(0.95);
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-grp">
  <div class="border">
    <a class="btn" href="#">Some really long text link #1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="border">
    <a class="btn" href="#">Some other really long text link #2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="border">
    <a class="btn" href="#">Some more really really long text link #3</a>
  </div>
  <div class="border">
    <a class="btn" href="#">The last really long text link #4</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Well for IE 8 support use `display:inline-block` and `transform` to place the content in center...

```css
.btn-grp {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
}

.border {
  width: 20%;
  height: 120px;
  border: 2px solid #1E5034;
  transition: all 250ms ease-out;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px;
}

a.btn {
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  font: 16px sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  display: block;
}

.border:before {
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #1f5034;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all .3s ease;
  transform: scale(0.85);
}

.border:hover:before {
  transform: scale(0.95);
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-grp">
  <div class="border">
    <a class="btn" href="#">Some really long text link #1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="border">
    <a class="btn" href="#">Some other really long text link #2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="border">
    <a class="btn" href="#">Some more really really long text link #3</a>
  </div>
  <div class="border">
    <a class="btn" href="#">The last really long text link #4</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, but I would like it centered on the page without using full width. For instance, even if you set it to 15% width, it will still stay to the left

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately it has to support IE 8. I'm not sure if this is really possible tbh. I do have an uglyish hack which will probably be good enough.

Comment: @Matt I also added the third solution for IE8 support using `display:inline-block`

Comment: this does work for IE9, doesn't appear to work for IE8. I am going to mess with transform though, see if I can get that to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Support in all browsers including IE.

```css
.btn-grp {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  width: 80vw;
}

.border {
  display: table;
  width: 25%;
  height: 120px;
  border: 2px solid #1E5034;
  transition: all 250ms ease-out;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-spacing: 10px;
  float: left;
}

.border:hover {
  border-spacing: 2px;
}

a.btn {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  font: 17.5px sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #1E5034;
  line-height: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

a.btn:hover,
a.btn:focus,
a.btn:active,
a.btn:visited,
a.btn:link {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #1E5034;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-grp">
  <div class="border">
    <a class="btn" href="#">Some really long text link #1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="border">
    <a class="btn" href="#">Some other really long text link #2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="border">
    <a class="btn" href="#">Some more really really long text link #3</a>
  </div>
  <div class="border">
    <a class="btn" href="#">The last really long text link #4</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you need the 4 `div` at vertically centered then use:

```
.btn-grp {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left:50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```